# Как заставить Selenide открыть Оперу вместо Лисицы

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, selenide

помогите с такой проблемой:
в селениум (JUnit) я понял как заставить его открывать оперу, а в селениде не знаю как это сделать, а он при попытке открыть сайт выдаёт Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. Вот собственно и всё. Вопрос в целом как и где в селениде прописывать браузер. Спасибо!

Comment: А прописать FF в path пробовал?

Comment: А браузер по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в ран конфигурацию `-Dselenide.browser=YOUR_BROWSER` где `YOUR_BROWSER` может принимать [одно из значений](https://ru.selenide.org/faq.html): `chrome`, `firefox`, `ie`, `phantomjs`, `htmlunit`, `safari`, `opera`.

Ну и системное свойство, хранящее путь к исполняемому файлу выбранного вебдрайвера, тоже надо не забыть установить.

В коде выбрать браузер можно таким образом:

```java
Configuration.browser = "opera";
```

**В идее делаем так:**

1. Запускаем тест (это сгенерит дефолтную ран-конфигурацию)
2. Идем сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Добавляем `-Dselenide.browser=opera` сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Вашем случае в левом кружке будет название Вашего класса и метода.

Comment: Подскажите, где это писать -Dselenide.browser=YOUR_BROWSER, что за ран конфигурация? В инете просто сразу показывают возможности селенида, без того как его настроить.

Comment: Какую среду разработки Вы используете?

Comment: Intelegy IDEA.. Заменил в мавене на более позднюю зависимость селенида, сработала команда WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(operaDriver);

Comment: Про идею обновил

Comment: Спасибо большое, исчерпывающе, нигде про это не видел. Единственное: Configuration.browser = "opera"; все равно не работает, после точки нету 'browser'. Т.е. в коде менять не могу.

Answer (score 0):

См. описание в вики селенида:  https://github.com/selenide/selenide/wiki/How-Selenide-creates-WebDriver

Comment: Из гита:

To run Selenide with any other web browser driver, just pass name of it's class to "browser" parameter:

java -Dselenide.browser=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
значит тут я не понял запись, Dselenid горит красным, вообще синтаксис этой записи не понял, может объясните?

Another option is to directly say Selenide use your desired WebDriver instance:

WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(myWebDriver).

здесь тоже прикольно - после точки нет метода сетдрайвер, только гет. Может что не импортировал? 
Спасибо за помощь.